# Is there a difference between Огонь - плох and Огонь - плохо?

Tags: грамматика

I am not a native, but I came across these two sentences on a thread over at [this thread on Linguistics.SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6181/did-a-cave-man-style-language-ever-exist?rq=1), and I had some kind of vague feeling the sentences did not mean *exactly* the same thing.

- Огонь - плох
- Огонь - плохо

Is there a difference, and if so what is it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1 **`Огонь плох`** (without a dash) is a combination of words, able to also stand as a sentence, which refers to the quality of fire, e.g. unstable, weak, producing little light etc

2 **`Огонь - плох`** (with a dash) is a sentence which may refer to adverse consequences of fire, it can be reworded as **`Огонь - он плох`**, it's bad as a destructive force

3 **`Огонь - плохо`** is a sentence which refers to the quality of a situation in which there's fire, it can be reworded as **`Огонь - это плохо`** and is unpacked as `it's bad when there's fire`

Abstract and general phenomena as well as predicate in impersonal sentences in Russian are expressed in neuter gender, that's why **`плохо`** doesn't refer to **`огонь`** but to the whole affair of its presence and/or activity

Comment: Note: #1 & #2 stand all right as they are. #3 is really asking for a reworded version (Огонь - **это** плохо). I think only children not older than 3 use the original version.